# to be vs being, how to use each one?

Tags: grammar, verbs

It is important for drones _____ integrated into the agriculture system.

A) being

B) in being

C) to be

D) be

The correct answer is C) to be, but why is not being?

Answer (score 1):

"Being" is wrong because the -ing form in that position creates a *reduced relative clause* modifying "drones", which means:

> It is important for drones *(that are) being* integrated into the agriculture system...

The phrase "*drones (that are) being integrated into the agriculture system*" is a single noun phrase, so it's not a complete sentence, and it doesn't say what about drones is important.

We can also look at why "to be" is correct.

If there's a verb after an adjective, it often has to be *[ "to" + base form ]*. This simplified structure is represented here:

> It is important **do**.

The base form "do" can be replaced by a more complex base form verb:

> It is important to **be integrated into the agricultural system.**

To specify the subject of "to be integrated", we use *[ "for" + subject ]*:

> It is important **for drones** to be integrated into the agricultural system.

Answer (score -1):

In that context the present participle "**being**" means "which are being",

> It is important for drones (which are) being integrated into the agriculture
> system...?

Important for them to do what? Important for them to be what? You haven't said WHAT is important!

So you might say,

> It is important for drones being integrated into the agriculture
> system *to be able to fly*.

Or,

> *The ability to fly* is important for drones being integrated into the
> agriculture system.

**But** you are trying to say this:

> **It is important for drones *to be* integrated into the agriculture
> system.**

By the way, if you were allowed to replace 'for' with 'that', you could choose option D:

> It is important *that* drones **be** integrated into the agriculture
> system.

[Option B - *in being* - isn't usable here.]

Comment: to be integrated is the answer. not being

Comment: @lambie: the answer to which question? Is it the answer to "how to use each one?" or is it the answer to "...but why is not being?" The OP didn't simply ask which is right.